# How to pin a search to sidebar for quick access in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I recently switched to a zero-inbox approach to using Gmail, archiving all messages I'm "finished" with. I like it, but there's one thing I miss: being able to see a list of recent messages that *were* in my inbox, including those I've archived. Before I used archive, this was the default view, and I found it very helpful for quickly finding recent emails.

Obviously I could use "All Mail", but the problem there is that it shows *all mail*, including messages I've sent and messages I've filtered out of my inbox (e.g. updates, calendar invites, etc.). Is there any way to see *only* messages that were at one point in my inbox?

The closest I can get to what I want is:

- Creating a search that gets rid of my junk filters (e.g. `NOT label:calendar NOT label:drive NOT label:announcements`). This doesn't work perfectly, but it's good enough. **My question is can I somehow *pin* this search to my sidebar to access it easily?**

Other things I've tried:

- Creating a filter to label to all messages that pass through the inbox with an "in-inbox" label. This doesn't work because filters can't operate on labels like "Inbox".
- Looking for a way to display achived messages *below* my inbox (like the Important and Unread vs Everything Else split), so they're easy to access, but not in my inbox. As far as I can tell, this ideal option is not supported.

Does anyone know how to address the limitations of the above, or have a better idea for how to deal with the problem?

Comment: I found that in an advanced search (down arrow at right of search box), after choosing range in **Date within** I can press `Tab`, then type `today` to gave me recent e-mails from the current selection: this can then be saved as a bookmark, eg all e-mails in the last week gives https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#advanced-search/subset=all&within=1w&sizeoperator=s_sl&sizeunit=s_smb&date=today. The only annoyance is that clicking the bookmark gives the drop-down search box, and i need to press `Esc` to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Until recently you could create custom filters at the sidebar by creating Gmail URL Gadgets if you had them enabled on Gmail Labs.

Unfortunately this function is now [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/gmail/sidebar_gadgets).

However you can make your filter in the search bar and bookmark in your browser the URL that contains your filters.

[image]